# Estimate vector $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ if $x_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,1)$ for $i=1,2$.

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, estimation

Assume $x_i\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_i,1)$ for $i=1,2$ and we are going to estimate vector $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$. If $\mu$ is located at a distance of 2 from the origin, then $\mu=(2\cos\theta,2\sin\theta)$ and the problem is to estimate $\theta$. For this let $\hat{\theta}=\arctan(x_2/x_1)$ and $-\pi<\hat{\theta}-\theta<\pi$.
Now the problem is to show $\hat{\theta}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and calculating $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\theta}-\theta)^2$ and then calculating error conditioned on $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2}$.
$\\$
I think if $P=(x_1,x_2)=(\hat{r},\hat{\theta})$ since $\mathbb{E}[x_1]=\mu_1$ and $\mathbb{E}[x_2]=\mu_2$ then intuitively $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ is an unbiased estimation of $\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}$ but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility, that the reason you are unable to prove it, is because it isn't true ? First of all $\hat{\theta}$ can only take values in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and will thus never be unbiased for theta outside this interval. I did some simulations with different values of $\theta$ and it definely doesn't look unbiased.

Comment: Also the expectation of $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ is in fact undefined, since the corresponding integral diverges and it does therefore not make sense to say wheter $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ is  unbiased for $\frac{\mu_1}{\mu_2}$.

Comment: Cross-post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/506078/119261.